# Mac App Sandboxing with Snow Leopard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I can't find any information on how to enable App Sandboxing with XCode on Snow Leopard? It seems like it's not possible but maybe one of you experts can confirm this or is there any workaround possible? Any hint will be valuable.
Thanks!

Comment: You have to have 10.6.8 or higher.  If I remember correctly, the highest Snow Leopard version is 10.6.9.  Unless you are going to use it for yourself, you really shouldn't develop anything suitable for 10.6.

Comment: Umm...  I was wrong.  I mixed it up with Mac App Store.  I should have referred Mac App Store, not sandboxing applications, to 10.6.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to develop a Sandboxed app, you really should be developing on at least 10.7.5 (preferably 10.9.1 at this point), since 10.7 was the first version of OS X to support sandboxing. Even if you could manage to build a sandboxing-enabled app on 10.6.8, you won't be able to properly test it.